# Laravel - How to generate pdf reports

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, dompdf

I'm developing an app that have a view with 3 table and 3 chart, I'm using framework bootstrap and chart.js. So my problem is that I need to allow to download this view as PDF file.

To do that I'm trying to use this : https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf but it returns 8 empty pages and don't give me any error and I don't understand why.

The code to generate the pdf is that:

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('backend.letter', compact('letter', 'stems', 'branches', 'hiddenStems', 'luckyStems', 'luckyBranches', 'hiddenStemsLuky', 'luckyYears'));
return $pdf->download('letter.pdf');
```

Anyone can help me?

Thank you

Comment: Did you **use PDF** ??

Comment: Yes @NikolasDiakosavvas . It don't give me any error

Comment: I have exactly the same code like you and it works.. The only difference is that I've created a different view for the pdf file.

Comment: Also, I have added this in my pdf's css style to display utf-8 characters : body { font-family: DejaVu Sans, sans-serif; }

Comment: Could be because I extend the main layout? @NikolasDiakosavvas

Comment: Maybe yes. In my case I don't extend the main layout. I've created a different style for that

Comment: Would help to have some info about the structure of your document (e.g. a sample of the HTML and CSS).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy with 
[wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) installed. This package has more functions and supports than DomPDF.